# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.core'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement Social Login in Django. I have already installed *social_auth_app_django* with below command

```
pip install social-auth-app-django
```

And I have also added this to installed apps in my settings file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
   'django.contrib.admin', 
   'django.contrib.auth', 
   'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
   'django.contrib.sessions', 
   'django.contrib.messages', 
   'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
   'social_django', 
   'mysite.core', 
]
```

But I'm getting the following error when I try to run migration

```
python manage.py migrate
```

> **ModuleNotFoundError**: No module named 'mysite.core'

**Note:** I'm using `Python 3.6.2` and `Django 1.11.7`

Comment: `mysite.core` should be in your Installed app.

Comment: Mysite .core must be declared in your installed_apps.

Comment: can you show your settings.py file.

Comment: I have already declared mysite.core in the installed app as: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django', 
    'mysite.core',
]

Comment: Please show the layout of your project, showing where `mysite.core` is located.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm have taken reference from this blog(https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html) for the project. There is not any installation of mysite.core app. mysite.core has been directly declared in the installed in teh Installed_apps file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial gets you to add views to an app `mysite.core`. You have added the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` but you haven't created it, so you get an import error.

The layout should be something like:

```
mysite/
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
└── __init__.py
```

The mysite directory belongs in your project directory (the one containing `manage.py`).

Another option is to remove `'mysite.core'` from `INSTALLED_APPS`. It isn't part of  `social-auth-app-django`. You'll then have to adjust the parts of the tutorial that create urls/views for `mysite.core`.

Comment: I have already tried it. It didn't work either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: If you need any more help then you need to show the project layout and the full traceback. Note that `mysite.core` isn't needed for `python-social-auth`, you could just remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` (although you will have to make changes to the tutorial later on if the `mysite/core` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 4):

This question is not even related to social_auth_app_django.

you were just saying django to add an app "core" which is inside mysite folder , and django is not able to found it.
what "alsadair" said is correct. you can do either one of the two things.

1) remove mysite.core, and run migrate.

2)create a app core inside mysite. and create an app means it should have app.py file. and it contain

```
 from django.apps import AppConfig
 class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
     name = 'core'
```

'core' is the name you include in installed_app which is getting checked.

Answer (score 1):

if the problem still persist, how about combining the forms.py code into your views.py then delete forms.py file so that you wont have to import anything other than

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```